# How to spread object inside object

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I Have an object inside another object and I want to spread the inner one, my reason is when I want to call the object by it's id

### My object

```
Resolver [
  { _id: { _id: '123456789', totaloutcome: 'DONE' }, count: 4 },
  {
    _id: { _id: '05000002', totaloutcome: 'OUTCOME_APPROVED_ONLINE' },
    count: 33
  },
  {
    _id: { _id: '05000002', totaloutcome: 'OUTCOME_CANCELLED' },
    count: 1
  },
  {
    _id: { _id: '05000002', totaloutcome: 'OUTCOME_UNKNOWN' },
    count: 1
  },
  {
    _id: { _id: '05000002', totaloutcome: 'OUTCOME_DECLINED' },
    count: 15
  }
]
```

As shown above I want to append 'count' attribut inside '_id' attribute , i couldn't spread the inner one so How can I do it

Comment: `array.map(({ _id, count }) => ({ ..._id, count }))` like this?

Comment: Or `array.map(({ _id, count }) => Object.assign(_id, { count }))` depending upon where you want the `count` property. If possible, fix this in the server side where you are grouping and counting.

Comment: I can't fix this in the server cuz it's the syntax of mongoDB , it's grouping method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the spread operator:

```
array.map((item) => {
  return { ...item, ...item._id };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**How to spread object inside object**

We are useing ... for spreding object into inner obj.

````
const user = {
  name:"siva",
  age: 25
}

//spred user in to below obj
const userInfo = {
   _id:"123445",
   phno: 77777777777
   ...user
}```
````

Comment: This answer was already given (using spreading).

Answer (score 0):

Code

```js
const Resolver= [
  { _id: { _id: '123456789', totaloutcome: 'DONE' }, count: 4 },
  {
    _id: { _id: '05000002', totaloutcome: 'OUTCOME_APPROVED_ONLINE' },
    count: 33
  },
  {
    _id: { _id: '05000002', totaloutcome: 'OUTCOME_CANCELLED' },
    count: 1
  },
  {
    _id: { _id: '05000002', totaloutcome: 'OUTCOME_UNKNOWN' },
    count: 1
  },
  {
    _id: { _id: '05000002', totaloutcome: 'OUTCOME_DECLINED' },
    count: 15
  }
]

const result = Resolver.map(({_id, ...rest}) => {
  return { ..._id, ...rest };
});

console.log(result)
```